Line art modifier - Rbdlab cell fracture issues
This is my first post, so please be kind :)
I’m using rbdlab to fracture an object into multiple cells (walls, doors, bricks, complex objects)
I use line art modifier to add some cool style to the wall..
The issue: Despite parts of the object looking completely flat.. grease pencil still draws lines on all of the internal “cracks” that make up an object
The goal: to be able to click play on the animation, and whatever does not seperate from its fractures will remain untouched by grease pencil, but still retain the exterior line art as normally expected without fracturing
The parts that do seperate from the object SHOULD have internal line art where the fractures are.
I don’t know how to approach this, 2 people have tried to make geo node setups for me but they barely work :(
If there’s a row of 10 fractured cells that visually don’t look fractured, and cell 5 and cell 6 seperate from the row, I want cell 5 and 6 to have line art applied internally, while cells 1-4 and 7-10 have external line art (not line art on the fractures)
What I have: original object pre fractured
Broken Cells that make up the overall original object (that looks visually together, but are really fractured)
Any thoughts on how I could approach this? It’s insane to me how such a simple idea is destroying me internally lol
Ps. If anyone needs me to specify anything just ask!
I had an idea on how this could be approached, but I am not sure if it’s plausible.
The differentiating factor that separates a fracture from the boarder of a wall is touching faces, the external faces don’t touch other faces- grease pencil should be drawn there
Internal faces that touch each other should be considered a fracture, as a fracture from cel 3 is touching a fracture in cel 5, the EDGES from those faces should not have grease pencil if those faces are touching in a certain threshold. Not sure if it’s possible but just a thought


Thanks. Hopefully someone here who uses grease pencil may be able to help.

I remember there was an experimental build with "Fracture Modifier" that worked in a way you are asking (I guess) it keeps model unfractured until shard should start move ... it solved common problem of glass material to render it unbroken before hit. ... old-school way is to animate visibility original and fractured model :)

@vklidu Yes, you are right, the "Fracture Modifier"... it was a special build but not officially from blender.org, unfortunately discontinued. That feature with the unbroken appearance I used a lot not only for glass. I made a short video with a few animations: Blender 2.79 Fracture Modifier - playing around. Another nice thing was, towards the end I used switching to slow motion sometimes - which would usually require animating several speeds when mixing rigid bodies, particles and smoke. There you animated one speed and it changed them all.
